# Tar: create new archive from filtered archive

Tags: linux, unix, tar

I need to create a new tar archive from the filtered output of the original. I thought something like this might work:

```
tar xvpf myarchive.tar --exclude=foo* | tar cvpf mynewarchive.tar
```

but that doesn't.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Almost there. That extracts to the filesystem. Adding `-O` or `--to-stdout` to the first tar and removing `v` (which would corrupt stdout) and `p` (doesn't make sense) should be sufficient.

Comment: Ah, getting closer. The second command complains still: tar: "no files or directories specified". How do I specify that it should take stdin?

Comment: I have come to the conclusion it cannot be done.